# Hard link '~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs' to ~/iCloud

Tags: finder, data-synchronization, icloud

Is it possible to do this at all? I've tried the following command:

```
ln /Users/Rowan/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents /Users/Rowan/iCloud
```

which results in:

```
ln: /Users/Rowan/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents: Is a directory
```

I can't seem to find how to add an argument to `ln` in order to 'allow' directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ln(1) on OS X does not support folder hard links. A symlink would work fine instead.

```
ln -s /Users/Rowan/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents /Users/Rowan/iCloud
```

If you really want a hard link, you can install coreutils with Homebrew and use

```
gln -d /Users/Rowan/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents /Users/Rowan/iCloud
```

Comment: I've decided to go with the second option, as it's prettier in the Finder. Thank you!

Comment: In MacOS 13.5.2, the second option (`gln -d`) returns the error `gln: failed to create hard link...`.