# Hardlinking to $HOME/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs

Tags: icloud, symlink, sonoma

How can the directory `~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs` be hardlinked to  the directory `~/iCloud? The [suggested answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/219549) to this question, based on the following command

```
gln -d  /Users/mpf/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs iCloud
```

throws this error on Sonoma 14.0:

```
gln: failed to create hard link './iCloud' => '/Users/mpf/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs': Operation not permitted
```

What is the correct approach?

Comment: APFS doesn't support hard links to directories.

Comment: What's the alternative? I need a way to avoid tildes "~" in the path. (These can sometimes cause issues with TeX via VSCode.)

Comment: You can always use /Users/USER instead of ~. And symlinking should work.